# Flutter return error on text selection.dart file on debug

Tags: flutter, flutter-file

when debugging the app it returns an error on text selection.dart file, and i dont found the aswer in the internet

here is the error details:

Error: Expected an identifier, but got '4133'.
text_selection.dart:716
Try inserting an identifier before '4133'.
final 4133DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
^^^^
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
text_selection.dart:716
final 4133DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
^^^^

: Error: Type 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' not found.
text_selection.dart:716
final 4133DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The non-abstract class 'RawEditorState' is missing implementations for these members:
raw_editor.dart:254

- TextInputClient.insertContent
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RawEditorState extends EditorState
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: 'TextInputClient.insertContent' is defined here.
text_input.dart:1117

void insertContent(KeyboardInsertedContent content) {}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' isn't a type.
text_selection.dart:716
final 4133DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Constructor is marked 'const' so all fields must be final.
text_selection.dart:634
const EditorTextSelectionGestureDetector({
^
: Context: Field isn't final, but constructor is 'const'.
text_selection.dart:716
final 4133DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\bruce\Desktop\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\bruce\Desktop\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1